# Jquery XML Parser

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to have a html5 video player (basic  tag), and call an external xml file in orderto load and play an ad before the main video.

This is currently working but I would like to have the cleanest and most multiplatform as possible:

```
function callAd() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",    
    url: myexternal_file,
    success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find('MediaFile[type="video/mp4"]').each(function(){
            var preroll = $(this)['context']['textContent'];
            var video = document.getElementById("video1");  
            video.src = preroll;
            video.load();
        });
    }
});
}
```

And as soon as the page loads, call the callAd function with my external xml.
How should I proceed whenever the external url isn't acessible?

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry, the question isn't clear. 
I would like to know how to correctly parse a XML using javascript/jquery and how should I correctly listen for events coming from this function.

Comment: What would you like to do? If the link doesn't work ADs won't show. Do you want to retry loading them after some time? Just like success: the ajax method also has error: that is being called when the URL is not accessible or returns wrong data format.

Comment: Hello, I would just like to play the video.
I only want the main video to load if we're certain that the external url isn't avaiable or there isn't any preroll to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `error` function when the URL in not available. If you want to use the resulted data you have to parse it. `jQuery.ajax` will do this automatically for you if you specify the `dataType`.

If the resulted data is not valid XML it will throw and error and script execution might end.

```
var retry = true;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",    
    url: myexternal_file,
    dataType: 'xml', // use dataType to parse the result as appropriate 
    success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find('MediaFile[type="video/mp4"]').each(function(){
            var preroll = $(this)['context']['textContent'];
            var video = document.getElementById("video1");  
            video.src = preroll;
            video.load();
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("Whoops, couldn't load ads: " + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        // wanna try again? uncomment below
        // if(retry) { callAd(); retry = false; }
    }
});
```